# Searching XML For Data via php

Tags: php, xml, search

I'm trying to search for data in a XML File using php.
I'm not trying to get values of certain elements, I would use xpath if I wanted that.

This is an example of my XML file:

```
<root>
<author>foo</author>
<date>bar</date>
</root>
```

Let's say my client wants to search for the words 'fab'.
I want all strings with the character 'f' and 'b' and 'a' to return.
So output would be:

```
Foo
bar
```

The author name could be James Westside for example.

```
<author>James Westside</author>
```

And the user searched for `jam`
it would return `James Westside`

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: please show some code what you have tried

Comment: i haven't tried anything at the moment, im pretty confused at what to do because im looking for strings from the xml file rather than grabbing the value of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PHP:s XMLReader class.  XMLReader acts as a cursor going forward on the document stream and stopping at each node on the way.

Something like this:

```
$search_phrase = 'fab';

$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open('your-xml-file.xml');

while ($xml->read()) {
  $node = $xml->expand();

  /* Looping through all elements in the XML */

  /* Test if the current node is a text node: */
  if ($node->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT) {

    /* Loop all letters in search_phrase */
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($search_phrase); $i++) {

      /* Test if the text in the text node is matching any letter i search_phrase: */
      if (strpos($node->nodeValue, substr($search_phrase, $i, 1)) !== false) {
        echo($node->nodeValue . "\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried this, is something something supposed to be in quotes or something
I get a parse error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/other_projects/musify/search_output.php on line 7 which is 'if($xml->readString() something something){'

Comment: can you tell me what if ($xml->readString() something something)
the something something after readString() is causing the error...

Comment: Thanks, i had arrived at a solution before you edited but your answer helps too :-)